# Make "[Meta]" display as "Meta"

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

I'm used to making comments like `See the [FAQ]` which render as:

> See the [FAQ](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq)

When I comment `Discuss on [Meta]` I get:

> Discuss on [Android Enthusiasts Meta](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/)

This is a bit redundant and awkward (in my opinion, of course).  Can we make it so it works the same way as the `[FAQ]` link?

> Discuss on [Meta](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/)

Or potentially:

> Discuss on [our Meta site](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/)
>
> [Our Meta site](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/) is great.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the whole point of the shortcuts is to make typing `[name of the site](http://link.to.the.site)` faster and less wasteful of precious comment characters. If you just want a link to the meta site, pasting in https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/ does just fine.

Gotta admit, I kinda like "our Meta site" as a less formal version of the text though.